# Two checkout pages in one instance of Magento - How?

Tags: magento, module, checkout

I have an client who uses Magento. They asked me to redesign the site and, in particular, change the way the current checkout page looks.

Summary:

> My goal is to create a new checkout module while still keeping the existing one. I'm not that familiar with
>   the core app so I was hoping I could take the current checkout module,
>   edit it's properties (like the name), change the checkout page
>   template for this new module, and save it as a newly created module.
>   Is that possible?

Like I said, I want to keep the current checkout module. I would like to just create a new checkout template page. Ideally we can have template A and template B for the same checkout module - one that will be the site default (the current site checkout process doesn't change) and one I will use to checkout guests that come in from landing pages.

However, can I duplicate a module and just edit the checkout page? Will that cause conflicts? Does anybody know of a way I can add a new checkout module that will only be used when I call it directly while still maintaining the current default checkout module for the site?

I will post back my results since this might be something other people might want to know.
THANKS!

Comment: Checkout customization is very involved, and based on the phrasing of this question, is likely beyond your ability (seriously not trying to be a dick here, just offering my opinion which is based on a good bit of experience).

Comment: Don't think that's a dick comment. If an experienced Magento developer tells me it's complicated, I take it seriously. Thanks for saving me even more hours of pointless research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We went with One Page Checkout. After showing a demo to the client, there was little need for convincing. It did all we needed and we are now able to easily modify the checkout process.

Thanks for the suggestion!

http://www.onestepcheckout.com/

Answer (score 2):

*I agree with Ben's comment above, this is not a straightforward undertaking for the inexperienced.*

My only constructive advice I can offer is to look at the implementation of both the `One page checkout` and `Multi address checkout` - it might give you some insight as to how multiple checkout mechanisms can co-exist.

But I would probably suggest not just changing the checkout on a whim - unless they have a tried and tested reason to change it. The last thing you want is to complicate the checkout procedure and encourage funnel drop-off's.

**Based on what your experience appears to be**, have you considered using an off-the-shelf extension for a customised checkout, there are many variations on the standard Magento one page checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I thought it would be simpler than it obviously is. I thought about looking @ One Page & Multi-address but I don't want to pay for something if I'm not really going to use.

Comment: One last question - Is there a way to have two different templates for the checkout process? The default checkout page can be simplified and we can't edit the current template (office politics) but we wanted to create a second page with a new design and still use the current code.

Comment: Ecomdev.org offer a developer-focused extension called CheckItOut which is documented and way more intuitive than standard OPC.

Comment: Thanks for the info, benmarks. We ended up using the "OneStep Checkout" module and it's worked out pretty nice.

Answer (score 1):

I voted up Katzumi's initial question (back to 0) as well as @sonassi's answer.

What brought me here is wanting to implement a POS (point of sale) checkout for our staff to use at special events. I was thinking of having a special checkout page just for the event.

Instead I got [IWD POS](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/iwd-pos-system.html). [Here's a link to their site](http://www.interiorwebdesign.com/magento/) if anyone else finds their way here.